# ruby on rails display one image from many images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I the following `Post` and `Attachment` models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy    
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

In my page I can only do like this:

```
<% post.attachments.each do |p| %>
  <%= image_tag p.image_url.to_s %>
<% end %>
```

This will show every image (every attachments) for a post.

If I only want to display the first image (when the attachment.id is minimum I guess) for a post. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will show the first attachment of the post:

```
<%= image_tag post.attachments.first.image_url.to_s unless post.attachments.blank? %>
```

Comment: I tried that. But It said that "undefined method `image_url' for nil:NilClass".. I dont know why. Because I can show many images now without this problem

Comment: that means some `post` don't have any attachment. So you can manage it by putting a condition. check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only trying to display the first attachment of a post you can do this:

```
<%= image_tag post.attachments.first.try(:image_url).to_s %>
```

instead of  iterating over all the attachments.